# Games consoles won't connect through the TP-Link TL-WA500G access point

Tags: wireless-access-point, xbox360, playstation

I have several laptops and other devices, all using my wireless router (*Sky Digital Netgear*). To extend the range to the back of the house, I purchased a *TP-Link TL-WA500G Range extender*, configured just as a pure repeater, which picks up the signal from the Netgear Router. The Netgear router does the DHCP, handing out the IP addresses.

This all works a treat with several different laptops and my iPhone 4S, but when my son tries to use his Xbox 360, Sony PlayStation 3 or the Nintendo Wii, **those devices fail to acquire an IP address**. They just sit there waiting for the IP config. This also happens with my wife's HTC Desire ONE Android phone.  My son says that when his HTC Desire C won't get an IP address, he just unplugs the AP briefly - the phone will connect and he puts the AP back on.

Once he is connected to the router, the AP won't disturb function. However the game consoles don't seem to work like that. They stop working when the AP is reconnected.

I had my son try to configure permanent IP addresses, and he said that it did not work either, though I have to confirm that as I did not see it for myself.

Has anyone seen this before? I have searched the Internet and have not found any similar problems anywhere. I wonder if there is a setting somewhere that would fix this.